# How do I add support for ECMA Script 6 promises on the client side?

Tags: javascript, spotify-app, es6-promise

I need to support ECMA script 6 promises in my web application on the client side. I'm using the Spotify Web API, which looks something like this

```
   // track detail information for album tracks

  spotifyApi.getAlbum('5U4W9E5WsYb2jUQWePT8Xm')
  .then(function(data) {
    return data.tracks.map(function(t) { return t.id; });
  })
  .then(function(trackIds) {
    return spotifyApi.getTracks(trackIds);
  })
  .then(function(tracksInfo) {
    console.log(tracksInfo);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I know that I can convert these to callbacks for backwards compatibility but that would be so much work and the code wouldn't look as clean.

Comment: You can get a polyfill on `//es6-promises.s3.amazonaws.com/es6-promise-2.0.0.min.js` (source [**here**](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise)) and you may have to `if (!window.Promise) window.Promise = ES6Promise.Promise;`

Comment: Client-side problems have to be solved with a library that provides a polyfill.  There are many to use such as Bluebird, Q and some others specifically targeted as an [ES6 polyfill](https://www.google.com/search?q=es6+promise+polyfill&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&oq=es6+promise+pol&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.3835j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).  If the spotify API is already using promises, it must have already provided a polyfill itself because it can't use them if they don't exist already.

Comment: You may also find this spotify wrapper useful: https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js.  Also, this conversation about how non-compliant Spotify promises were to the spec: https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/issues/24.  This is a 2013 discussion, don't know if that's been fixed.